# Using temporary variables in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, performance

I am writing a function that shuffles the item in an array:

```
this.shuffle = function () {
    ...
```

First, I get the two halves of the array and set up a third empty array:

```
    this.leftHalf = this.cards.slice(0, this.size() / 2);
    this.rightHalf = this.cards.slice(this.size() / 2);
    this.result = [];
```

Next, I put one card from each half into the result array:

```
    for (var i = ...) {
        this.result.unshift(this.leftHalf[i]);
        this.result.unshift(this.rightHalf[i]);
    }
```

Last, I assign the result array to my original array and delete the "temporary" variables:

```
    this.cards = this.result;

    delete this.leftHalf;
    delete this.rightHalf;
    delete this.result;
}
```

My question: Is this a sensible way to approach this problem, or is there a better way that doesn't involve setting up temporary variables? I thought about using private variables instead (but wasn't sure if it would be any better performance wise) like so:

```
var leftHalf, rightHalf, result;

this.shuffle = function () {
    leftHalf = ...
```

Just curious if there was anything obvious I'm doing wrong or if there's a best practice in these cases.

Comment: The "temporary variables" you create are properties.  If you are going to delete them anyway, just use `var`.  I wouldn't worry about performance, since that is what they are for.

Comment: Also, your shuffle algorithm is highly predictable. I recommend looking at using a [real shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: @GregHewgill I think he wants a perfect shuffle like he is doing since he never uses the word random anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without any private variables and one loop through although I doubt there will be much performance difference.  Assuming you want a left hand shuffle so the card on the top ends up on top and and card in the middle ends up second and the length of your deck is an even number N...

```
for(var i=...) {
   if(i%2 == 1) 
      newdeck[i] = oldeck[N/2+(i-1)/2];
   if(i%2 == 0) 
      newdeck[i] = oldeck[i/2];
}
```

This will do what is called a perfect shuffle like your original algorithm does, but as people have said this is not random in the sense that it is predictable.  There is a famous paper saying that to reach a random seeming deck from an ordered one you need to run 7 perfect shuffles.  You can also control cards in the deck using right and left shuffles as in [this article](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/crux/2012/07/16/surprising-connection-between-card-shuffling-higgs-boson/).

Comment: I just thought it was clearer what the cases were but of course you could use else.  One case is if even and the other is if odd but they are complementary.

Comment: I think the claim about 7 shuffles is that you need 7 normal riffle shuffles (and this is assuming a 52-card deck) to get a random-seeming deck. After 7 perfect shuffles (interleavings of halves), you will have a lot of structure.

Comment: The interleaving of halves is what a riffle shuffle is... ?  And yes for different number of cards than 52 the number of shuffles needed is different.  The claim is not that it will be unpredictable -- all you have to do is run the algorithm either forwards or backwards -- the claim is that it will have all the statistical properties of being random, i.e. no long sequences of the same suit or color. More accurately you can't get it to look more random than at 7 shuffles no matter how many you do is the claim.

Comment: I was using riffle shuffle to mean what a person does when they shuffle cards (so not a perfect shuffle). Here's a link to an article about the paper: http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/course/topics/winning_number.html
Note that it says explicitly 7 imperfect shuffles.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good algorithms for randomizing the order of a set of elements. One straightforward one is to swap the last element with a random element of your list. Then swap the n-1th element with a random one of the first n-1 elements (assuming your list is n long), then swap the n-2th element with a random one of the first n-2 elements, etc. (Note that you might swap an element with itself.)

The naive implementation of this will use one temporary variable, but there are tricks to make it be entirely in place. Those are almost never necessary and usually reduce readability.

Comment: The naive implementation will just call `.sort(function() {...})` on the array and use `Math.random()` to return one of {-1,0,1}

Comment: But he doesn't want to randomize it he wants to do a perfect shuffle, IE interleaving the cards

Comment: Well, you were the one who brought the randomization to the discussion ;-)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. I guess when I hear the word "shuffle" in the context of, say, an array, rather than a deck of cards, I interpret that as random. I agree that the code suggests he wants an interleaving of the two halves of the list, but I (perhaps mis)interpreted it as a bad randomization. Hopefully, even if it's not what the OP had in mind, my answer will still be useful to somebody who comes here based on the word shuffle.

Comment: This sounds like a good method. I will have to implement it later, but for now I am just trying to get something close to working :)

Comment: Just for the thrills: a.sort(function() {return Math.random() - 0.5;});

Answer (score 0):

When we say the term Shuffle, it do have to be random. Below is a snippet that I created to demonstrate rearranging the arral values in a random way.

```
var shuffle = function() {

        var _deck = [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M" ],
        _shuffle = [],
        _slice; 

        do {

           // return's a random index
           _splice = Math.floor( Math.random() * _deck.length );

           // store the random value in new array
           _shuffle.push( _deck[ _splice ] );

           // splice the random value
           _deck.splice( _splice, 1 );

        } while ( _deck.length );

    };
```

As @hackartist mentioned you could read this http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/crux/2012/07/16/surprising-connection-between-card-shuffling-higgs-boson/ and further extend to shuffle method to self-execute X number of times